# error message at start ubuntu 12.04

Tags: boot

I am getting the below message  in a long queue and flashing when switching on my laptop. It actually lets me in after a very long time (even 30 mins or more). After getting in, the internet connection is working only for a few seconds minutes and then drops. if I re-boot the router, it reconnects me very hardly to both wired and wireless and then drops me down again. Internet connection is working perfectly from other devices and it did before.

```
/dev/sda1: clean, 904718/9641984 files, 35754533/38550272 blocks 
fsck from util-Linux 2.20.1
/dev/sda1: clean, 904718/9641984 files, 35754533/38550272 blocks 
fsck from util-Linux 2.20.1
/dev/sda1: clean, 904718/9641984 files, 35754533/38550272 blocks 
fsck from util-Linux 2.20.1
/dev/sda1: clean, 904718/9641984 files, 35754533/38550272 blocks 
fsck from util-Linux 2.20.1
/dev/sda1: clean, 904718/9641984 files, 35754533/38550272 blocks 
fsck from util-Linux 2.20.1
```